# Fixed size table with column spanning on IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, html-table

I'm trying to make a table in html, using fixed sizes and column spanning.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
<table style="width:602px;" border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="height:148px; width:298px;" colspan="2"></td>
    <td style="height:148px; width:298px;" colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="height:148px; width:148px;"></td>
    <td style="height:148px; width:298px;" colspan="2">content</td>
    <td style="height:148px; width:148px;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="height:148px; width:148px;"></td>
    <td style="height:148px; width:298px;" colspan="2"></td>
    <td style="height:148px; width:148px;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="height:148px; width:148px;"></td>
    <td style="height:148px; width:298px;" colspan="2"></td>
    <td style="height:148px; width:148px;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This works as I expect on chrome (creating 2 double length cells in the first row, and then three rows of single-double-single length cells). However, in IE8 the middle cell in the bottom 3 cells is sized to fit the "content", not to the size I defined.

Am I doing something wrong, and how should I change this to make it work as I want? Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your table width, and you'll see how your table behave...

Yes, all your columns are trying to be 298px wide. This is because a table try to fit its column width with its first row... Remove the useless declaration and try this :

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td  style="height:148px;"  colspan="2">1fdasfsdafsdfas</td>
    <td  colspan="2">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="height:148px; width:148px;">1</td>
    <td style="width:298px;" colspan="2">1</td>
    <td style="width:148px;">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="height:148px;">1</td>
    <td colspan="2">1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="height:148px;">1</td>
    <td colspan="2">1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```